# Submitting tasks to be executed at night

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

We've got a web application (Spring based) where users can submit some tasks which are ran in a single background thread. We're using a [TaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) where we submit runnables for that, and they are processed as soon as the executor thread is free.

Now we'd like to **not** run these jobs immediatly, but start processing them, sequentially, at a certain hour at night. Until that time, they all would be queued awaiting. We don't know how many jobs there will be on a day, nor how much time they will take, so we don't want to schedule them individually at fixed hours.

I've taken a look to Spring's Quartz integration but I haven't found anything useful so far. It would be nice if those pending jobs were somehow persisted so they would survive reboots.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take consists of storing each task in a database, as soon as it is submitted.

Then, at night, you could run a job that queries the database and processes the returned tasks, sequentially. When the processing of each task has finished, you could either delete the task from the database or mark it as processed.

*If there happened to be many tasks, you could process them in batches.*

A sketch of that job could be:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "some_time_at_night")
public void runJob() {
    // Query non processed tasks from the database
    List<Task> tasks = database.getNonProcessedTasks();
    // Iterated over returned tasks
    for (Task t : tasks) {
        try {
            // Process current task
            this.process(t);
            // Mark current task as processed in database or delete it
            database.updateTaskAsProcessed(t);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Handle ex, either log it or store it for further reference
        }
    }
}

private void process(Task t) {
    // Perform processing here
}
```

Spring supports cron expression by means of the [`@Scheduled` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled).

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I hoped there was some more "automated" solution with minimal changes to the existing code, but I think I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have these tasks surviving reboot would be to persist them and their datas in some kind of DBs.

For the schedule matter I would use a @Scheduled annotation on a specific service which would call the tasks from the DB or your executor's queue then process them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know serializing the tasks to disk/bd was the only option, but I hoped there was some way to automatically do it with Quartz retaining the TaskExecutor interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cron expressions:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* 2 * * *")
public void doSomething() {
}
```

This, for example would run at 2 a.m. every day.

The [`CronTrigger`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html) class could be also of use to you, there is a short section about it in the official Spring docs, which you have linked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@Scheduled` annotation on the method which give a call the `TaskExecutor` as

**Example :**

```
@Scheduled (cron="0 0 2 * * ? *", fixedDelay = 5000)
public void updateEmployeeInventory(){
    System.out.println("Started fixed delay job");
    /**
     * add your scheduled job logic here
     */
}
```

**fixedDelay :** Incase, if you specify fixed delay as 5 seconds, then the annotated method would be invoked at every 5 seconds with a fixed delay, meaning that the period will be measured from the completion time of each preceding invocation.

More details on this will be find in the links below:-

1. [Schedule jobs using @Scheduled annotation in spring](http://www.java2novice.com/spring/schedule-job/)
2. [CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)